# Improve moderator tools integration of the keyboard shortcuts

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, keyboard-shortcuts

The mod tool integration for the new keyboard shortcuts (which are absolutely magical, by the way) is a bit spotty:

---

*Exhibit A: "I don't have a 10 key!*

[image: I don't have a 10 key]

*Exhibit B: "How do I clicky?"*

[image: How do I clicky]

---

But the thing I am currently complaining about the most is that there's no way to handle flags via keyboard shortcut:

[image: MUST HANDLE FLAG]

Could moderators please get some love with the keyboard shortcuts?

Other various things that need shortcuts for mods:

- basically everything under /admin
- user profile pages
- comments (upvote, flag, edit, delete)

Comment: "I don't have a 10 key" -- Clearly we need a kickstarter to build a keyboard that's not bound by arbitrary limits like this.

Comment: A possible solution for the 10 key problem is to replace it by the 0 key.

Comment: "I don't have a 10 key", "How do I clicky" (M -> I) and "user profile pages" are fixed/added now.